# how to get function return array value in php 5.5?

Tags: php, arrays, function, return

I tried to dump the array inside the function and I get all the value I wanted. But after return to $uplines, it shows me null. I have no idea why.  Tried 2 arrays by using list($array1,$array2) still null for me. Can someone point me out? if im wrong. Thanks and cheers!

```
$uplines= $this->getTotalUpline($member,$level,$array1,$no);
```

Here is the function:

```
function getTotalUpline($member,$count,$array1,$no)
{
    $memberUplineId = $member->getUplineDistId();
    $c = new Criteria();
    $c->add(MlmDistributorPeer::DISTRIBUTOR_ID,$memberUplineId);
    $exist = MlmDistributorPeer::doSelectOne($c);

    if($exist && $memberUplineId != 1)
    {
        $array1[$count][0] = $exist->getDistributorId();
        $array1[$count][1] = $exist->getAccountType();

        $count++;
        $this->getTotalUpline($exist,$count,$array1,$no);
    }
    elseif($memberUplineId == 1)
    {
        var_dump($array1);
        return $array1;
    }
}
```

Comment: your `If block` does not return the `array` please add to it. Or add at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Possible pointer: You only return the $array1 on the elseif block. 
if the condition is false then the default return value is NULL (no explicit return)

```
 elseif($memberUplineId == 1)
{
    var_dump($array1);
    return $array1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
The condition is always correct unless it found the id is 1 which mean the highest id den it will return all the $array element.which mean I have to move out the return outside the if statement?

Comment: you can try move the return $array1 outside the elseif block if it make sense logically with the code.  The code as it stand now will only return $array1 untouched when $memberUplineId == 1 or null otherwise.

Comment: I had fixed the problem. Make the array as reference.

$this->getTotalUpline($member,$level,$uplines,$no);

There are 2 ways to fix the problem, add an '&' at the function parameter
1) function getTotalUpline($member,$count,&$array1,$no)

or add another 'return' inside the if statement

2) $this->getTotalUpline($exist,$count,$array1,$no);

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed the problem. Make the array as reference in the function parameter.

$this->getTotalUpline($member,$level,$array1,$no);

======================================================================
There are 2 ways to fix the problem, add an '&' at the function parameter

1) function getTotalUpline($member,$count,&$array1,$no)

or add another 'return' inside the if statement

2) $this->getTotalUpline($exist,$count,$array1,$no);

Complete function:

```
function getTotalUpline($member,$count,$array1,$no)
    {
        $memberUplineId = $member->getUplineDistId();
        $c = new Criteria();
        $c->add(MlmDistributorPeer::DISTRIBUTOR_ID,$memberUplineId);
        $exist = MlmDistributorPeer::doSelectOne($c);

        if($exist && $memberUplineId != 1)
        {
            $array1[$count][0] = $exist->getDistributorId();
            $array1[$count][1] = $exist->getAccountType();

            $count++;
            return $this->getTotalUpline($exist,$count,$array1,$no);
        }
        return $array1;
    }
```